# Executar bloco de código Lua dentro do C++

Tags: c++, lua, interoperabilidade

Como faço para executar um bloco de código Lua dentro de uma função em C++?

A ideia seria algo como:

```
int main() {
  tipodavariavel script;
  script << "print('Ola mundo')";
  executar(script);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este é um exemplo de código básico para executar um *script* Lua. Note que essencialmente é usado sintaxe C:

```
extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
}
 
int main() {
    lua_State *L = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaL_dostring(L, "print('Ola mundo')");
    lua_close(L);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/8e1c04abdad83eda7a90bc61a8272232611e1bed/Lua/InteropC.c).

Para compilar deve usar algo assim usando o GCC/MinGW:

```
g++ -o interpetadorlua.cpp -llua -ldl
```

De uma forma geral é isto, não sei se você precisa de alguma coisa específica.

[Lista de várias bibliotecas](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BindingCodeToLua) com exemplos que podem ajudar na integração de diversas maneiras se desejar formas mais alto nível e abstratas de tratar o problema.

Comment: Preciso executar inline.

Comment: O que você chama de *inline*?

Comment: Editei a pergunta.
Seria executar direto de lá, sem usar outro arquivo.